# Asynchronous execution error on AWS Cognito registering method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm making an user management with the Amazon Web Service names Cognito.

It runs smoothly on local but it is not when I use it on a Wamp server.

I can not figure out why... maybe cause to asynchronous execution ?

I'm using `$q` and `.then(function() { ... });` to wait for it's execution.

This is how I do in my controller :

```
  $scope.validateForm = function() {
         if (AuthService.getActifUser() == false) {
             //clear local storage
             $storage.remove('userData');
         }
         //getting the form attributes
         var datafirstName = {
             Name: 'custom:first_name',
             Value: $scope.firstName
         };
         var dataLastName = {
            Name: 'custom:last_name',
            Value: $scope.lastName
         };
         var dataEmail = {
            Name: 'email',
            Value: $scope.email
         };
         var attributeFirstName = AuthService.setAttributes(datafirstName);
         var attributeLastName = AuthService.setAttributes(dataLastName);
         var attributeEmail = AuthService.setAttributes(dataEmail);
         var attributeList = [];
         attributeList.push(attributeFirstName);
         attributeList.push(attributeLastName);
         attributeList.push(attributeEmail);
         // signing try
         AuthService.signin($scope.username, $scope.password, attributeList)
         .then(function(res) {
             // save username in local storage
             $storage.set('userData', $scope.username);
             // go to the verification page
             routeService.goToView('/users-confirmation');
       }, function(res) {
          console.log(res);
       );
     }
```

And in the AuthService Factory :

```
  AuthService.signin = function(username, password, attributeList) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        userPool.signUp(username, password, attributeList, null, function(err, result) {
             if (err) {
                alert(err);
                deferred.reject('registering failled.');
             }
             console.log('successfully registered.');
             deferred.resolve('successfully registered.');
         });
         return deferred.promise;
      };
```

Unfortunatelly the `routeService.goToView()` method is never called.

Hope someone know why ?

Comment: Your angular controller missing it!

Comment: Thanks @geminiousgoel for your answer but I'm not sur to understand...

Answer (score 0):

Could you please add a handler for the promise rejection to ensure that the promise is not being rejected?

It could be that your promise is being rejected and the error hidden. Also, where is `invalidPassword` being defined?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have edited the code in my question. Unfortunately there is no console.log print on my console...